# Use "Lock Screen" as Daydream option

Tags: lock-screens, charging, screen, wireless-charging, daydream

maybe its too simple a question, but I need to figure out how I can just use my lock-screen as daydream option for an android lollipop device.

What I want is to see the normal lock screen while charging (specifically wireless charging) instead of turning off the screen. How can I do that?

update July '15: I think it is just not possible - how dull!

Comment: I thought of a workaround using Developer Options' Stay Awake while charging, but it makes the phone impossible to auto-lock. Not a problem if you set the lock to instantly and not forgetting to press power button twice to lock (won't post as an answer since it doesn't really work as required, unless requested)

Comment: I had also tried that. But very unsatisfactory :)

Comment: If you are open to a very simple automation I can suggest